# Convert JSON to string from SQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an app that should display a string in a textview after the buttons are clicked; instead it displays the JSON format of the code, not the uncoded JSON. Here is my android code:

```
    package game.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class JSONtestActivity extends Activity {

String result = "";
InputStream is = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            returnJson();

        //end of onClick    
        }
    //end of onClickListener
    });


//end of oncreate()    
}

public void returnJson(){

    TextView one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new       HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_list.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        one.setText("error3");
    }

    try{


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);                      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "/n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        one.setText("error2");          
        }

    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("log_tag","story_name: "+json_data.getString("story_name") 
                    );
            result += "\n" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 



        }
        one.setText(result);
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        one.setText("error1");
    }
        return;


//end of returnJson()   
}



//end of class body    
}
```

and my php

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root");
mysql_select_db("textures_story_list");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT story_name FROM story_list WHERE story_name LIKE 'sto%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Can someone help with this? It doesn't display the names instead of the json format. This is what it displays in the textview instead of "story one", "story two" and so on:

```
[{"story_name":"Story One"}
 {"story_name":"Story Two"}, 
 {"story_name":"Story Three"}, 
 {"story_name":"Story Four"},
 {"story_name":"Story Five"},
 {"story_name":"Story Six"}]/n{"story_name":"Story One"},
 {"story_name":"Story Two"},
 {"story_name":"Story Three"},
 {"story_name":"Story Four"},
 {"story_name":"Story Five"},
 {"story_name":"Story Six"}
```

Comment: Let me get this straight: you're using json_encode() on the retrieved record before printing it, and then wondering why the string is shown json encoded?

Comment: Does the log entry `Log.i("log_tag", "story_name"`... show the correct string value or does it exhibit the same issue?

Comment: yes i encod it in php to json then sent it to android with httppost and need to now decode it to normal english but not sure how to do it, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: sorry tarek im not sure how log_tag works.

Comment: mark im not wondering why its still in JSON, i knew that im wondering how to change it to a normal string

Answer (score 1):

I might be too much of a preacher, but every time it comes to parsing string to objects in java I recommend using [Gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). It is lightweight and works perfectly fine on Android too. For your particular case, you might be able to go parsing the string yourself, but as I assume this is not going to be the only place you need to parse json, the library might help you. Here is my suggestion:

Declare a class to which the json will be deserialzied:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Story {
    @SerializedName(story_name)
    private String storyName;
}
```

And then deserialize your string to this class:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Story [] stories = gson.fromJson(is, Story[].class);
```

From then on you can iterate over this object array and use it however you like.

Couple of **notes**:

- The '\n' is written \n not /n.
- The logging is absolute requirement to know if you are coding for
  Android. Basically you just write `Log.i("Log tag", "My first log
  message");` the `Log` is a class that android provides you (you still
  will need to import it of course). `i` is the log level you can
  choose between e(error), w(warning), i(info), d(debug), v(verbose).
  `Log tag` is just a string, basically you can place whatever you like
  there - I would suggest the class Name. Finally when this line is
  executed you will see in your LogCat `My first log message`. Logging
  is very useful to detect problems in the cod,e because you can
  display variable values at certain points of your program.

Comment: boris that helped alot ill try gson and see how that goes, im only new to android but picking it up fast, again thanks for your help